# IIS Web App Login Prompt with Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, windows-authentication

There are many questions like this but I have not come across one that matches my criteria.

My issue is as follows:

I have an ASP.NET webapp A deployed to a production webserver (2008 R2) using Win Auth and it works with no issues , for everyone.

A colleague then deployed the same site to a new development server (2012 R2) and I, for example, can browse the website with no issue. However three of my colleagues receive a login prompt which even after filling in, does not let them through to the site.

We have checked to ensure that the settings are exactly the same in IIS Manager for the site.

Checked the app pool is set up the same as well.

The app web config is also identical.

Checking the header on the prod site showed that kerberos is not being used.

Really struggling with this one so any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

KS

Answer (score 0):

When you open IIS Manager, expand Sites, click on the site, double-click Authentication, and compare the settings you have there.  Click Windows Authentication and then Providers and remove Negotiate:Kerberos from this list if it is there.  Move NTLM to the top of the list.

[image]

If your users that cannot authenticate are still having issues, try clearing their Internet Explorer settings.  You can also have them try adding this site to Trusted Sites.

The Event Viewer on this server will also tell you the reason authentication failed and you can use that to troubleshoot further.  Have one of the users impacted try, note the time they tried, and find a corresponding error entry.

Comment: Nope, that did not help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Was there anything in the Error Viewer at the time of the authentication attempt?  It could be that the application pool account doesn't have access to read the web directory or query the active directory.  The errors that are recorded on the server in the Error Viewer when the authentication attempt is made will be your best bet.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check IIS setting...you are receiving prompt because of IIS .Set Windows Authentication disable